# Spring Boot run task at 5 defined times

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I have a method in my spring boot application that I want to be called every 4h and additionally on 5 fixed times.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */4 * * ?")
public void triggerOptimization() {
}
```

Is it possible to add several cron expressions on the method or how else can I define 5 defined times to trigger the method additionally?

Comment: I dont think its possible. You might have to work around it by creating multiple scheduled tasks. But you might find this interesting: https://crontab.guru/